# Link2SD made apps unable to reinstall after SD card corrupted

Tags: applications, sd-card, installation, internal-sd, link2sd

I was using Link2SD and linked some of my apps to an SD card including internal data. Recently, the second partition somehow got corrupted. I deleted the partition and reformated it. Now I can't install any of the apps previously linked. It shows insufficient space error, but there is plenty of space in internal memory, SD card, as well as SD card's 2nd partition, and I can install any other apps.

I tried the clean-up option in Link2SD. It cleaned up the Dalvik cache of old linked apps, but it didn't work.

What to do now?

Comment: Try 1) uninstalling and re-installing affected apps and, if that doesn't work, 2) try a cleaner app. What I suspect is that the *links* created by Link2SD still exist (they are created in the original place, pointing to your "external storage") – but now pointing nowhere. Android tries to follow-up and … well, nothing there, 0 byte available at the (ex-) target. If that's the case, those links need to be removed. You could do that manually if you know your way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Go to application manager
2. There are some filenames starting with '.com' and with a grey SD card icon
3. Uninstall them
   That should do the work